# Use different font for math fragments in org mode

Tags: org-mode, regular-expressions, font-lock

How do I use the fixed-pitch font for math fragments in org-mode buffers? I.e., I want to use a monospace font for all strings of the form `\(...\)` or `\[...\]`, where `...` may include newline characters as well, as is common for equations written in math display mode. Note that I am *not* referring to the org special source buffer that edits these fragments in a separate latex-mode buffer.

I'm an Emacs newb, so the best I could come up with was a regex-based font-lock:

```
(progn
  (setq-local font-lock-keywords
              `((,(rx (group
                       (or "\\[" "\\(")
                       (zero-or-more anything)
                       (or "\\]" "\\)"))) (1 'fixed-pitch))))
  (font-lock-fontify-buffer))
```

And then running this on an org-mode-hook.

But this is definitely wrong. Not only does it remove all the nice org-mode styling applied to things like section headers, but it's also applying the fixed-pitch font to more than just the intended math fragments, suggesting issues with the regex at least.

Comment: One problem is that you are setting `font-lock-keywords` to the one thing you want, thereby throwing away any other entries that Org mode was careful to add: that probably explains why the rest of the Org mode styling goes away. Another problem is that `(zero-or-more anything)` probably matches too much: in particular, it should not match `\)` or `\]` since they are supposed to close the matching substring. In general, regexps that try to match an opening string, followed by "stuff", followed by a closing string are complicated beasts that may not always work.